# What is the best way to change the hash password on new Django?

Tags: python, django, hash

Bcryptpasswordhasher was removed on Django2.1.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/#removed-bcryptpasswordhasher-from-the-default-password-hashers-setting

How should I change the password of existing user? Should I switch to another hasher and then let the user change the password?
Also, which hasher is best to use?

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/naohide/Workspace/python3/django-project/project/users/tests_api.py", line 673, in test_something
    self.client.login(username='abc', password='aaaaaaaa')
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 602, in login
    user = authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 26, in authenticate
    if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 111, in check_password
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 61, in check_password
    setter(password)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 107, in setter
    self.set_password(raw_password)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 98, in set_password
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 78, in make_password
    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
  File "/Users/naohide/.virtualenvs/django-project/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 417, in encode
    return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, data.decode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get a definitive answer to *which hasher is best to use* here. Unless you have a good reason, I would use the default `PASSWORD_HASHERS`. If you are migrating from an earlier version of Django and have passwords using different hashers, then add them to the list so that the passwords can be upgraded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I was using py-bcrypt, but I needed to use [bcrypt](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/)

And, All fixed for me.

Answer (score 1):

`Bcryptpasswordhasher` wasn't removed from Django 2.1. It was removed from the list of default password hashers.

If you still have passwords in your database that use `BCryptPasswordHasher`, then you can include it in your `PASSWORD_HASHERS`, e.g.

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    # Default list in 3.1 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#password-hashers
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    # Manually include BCryptPasswordHasher
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

Then, when these users log in, their password will be upgraded to use the first entry in the list. When there are no more `BCryptPasswordHasher` hashes in your database, it is safe to remove `BCryptPasswordHasher` from the list.

Comment: looks good. thanks. but, when I still try to use BCryptPasswordHasher, I'm having an error with python3.7.5. File "/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 417, in encode return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, data.decode('ascii'))

Comment: I can't tell the problem from that line. Please include the full traceback in your question. What are you doing when you get that error?

Comment: sorry, I added my error. It happens in my testcase.

Comment: We can't help debug a test case if you don't show it.